# Preferred formatting for this / best practice?

Tags: php, code-formatting

Suppose I want to create a select box in PHP.

`$months = array ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');`

Option 1:

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="">-------</option>
    <?php foreach ($months as $monthNum => $month) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $monthNum+1 ?>"><?php echo $month ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Option 2:

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="">-------</option>
    <?php 
        foreach (months() as $monthNum => $month) 
            echo '<option value="' . ($monthNum+1) . '">' . $month . "</option>\n"; 
?>
</select>
```

I personally think Option 1 renders the code harder to read and understand, at the same time Option 2 screws the indentation and puts more HTML into PHP.

Which option is preferred?

EDIT: I don't want to add another template engine on top of PHP, which is itself a template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second option is better because things like `<option value="<?php echo $monthNum+1 ?>">` simply are hard to read and understand and imho even a little bit illogical (a tag in a tag.)

But honestly, use what you like more. Only one suggestions: Maybe instead of using `<?php foreach () { ?> ... <?php } ?>` which is sometimes hard to understand you may use this syntax: `<?php foreach (): ?> ... <?php endforeach; ?>`. Especially if you start having foreaches in fors in whiles in foreaches in fors this syntax may be a little bit easier to understand.

Comment: I gave +1 because of the suggestion to use template tag style, but I almost refrained from upvoting because of the comment that a tag within a tag is illogical. PHP code is enclosed in an XML processing instruction, not a tag: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi

Comment: And what if I am using HTML, not XHTML? Than it can hardly be an XML processing instruction, can it? ;) I simply used the word most people would understand best.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 no doubt, is semantic where is php is php where is html is html

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a) what ever is easier to maintain for you and your colleagues and b) consistency.

If you (and your colleagues) think that 1 is harder to read and understand then don't use it. In 6/12/18 months time when you come back to the code it will be even harder to understand than it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use Option 1, because I consider it a supreme priority to keep HTML and PHP code as separate as possible.

If it helps, I often use the shorthand `<?= 'value'; ?>` instead of `<?php echo 'value'; ?>`.

Comment: I personally think that's a bad idea because that shorthand requires short_open_tags to be on, which is not always the case.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely realize that, but I fortunately work in an environment where it doesn't become an issue. I would agree, though, that it's NOT for everyone, especially when there's lots of vendor type of work and you don't have control over the server configuration (or htaccess).

Answer (score 1):

I think option 1 is perfectly fine to read. However, if you do not like the lonely } at the end, you could use [php's alternativ syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (using endforeach).

Comment: I love the template tag syntax. Strangely though, there is no alternative form of `try...catch`. Seems like it would be logical to have `try, catch, endcatch`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion option 2 reads like a script that spits out some strings, where option 1 reads like an HTML template with embedded PHP code. For view templates in an MVC framework, I find that option 1 is the best looking and easiest to read. For CLI or other purposes, option 2 works better.